# How to change base in tag URL for custom post type, to not use "Custom Structure" set in Permalinks setting?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

In Permalink Settings for Custom Structure we have set it to the following so our News pages have news in the URL:

```
/news/%postname%/
```

We have also created custom post types and custom taxonomy for those post types, for example, a directory CPT with a Locations tag.

We have changed the custom post type URL to /directory/ thats fine, but I cannot find how to change the TAG URL structure. Tags only work with the following URLs:

```
/news/locations/new-york/
```

But I would want to have it as:

```
/directory/locations/new-york/
```

I would also like to do it for categories too.

I cant find anything online.

Comment: So your CPT also supports the `post_tag` taxonomy and you want another permalink structure with `directory` being the base, e.g. `example.com/directory/tag/foo-tag` ? That would lead to duplicate content penalty because both URLs would display the same posts? Or did you want `directory/tag/foo-tag` to show only posts in your CPT that are tagged with `foo-tag`?

Comment: But if that is the case, then why don't you just use a custom taxonomy for your CPT, e.g. `directory_tag`? That way, you'd be able to set the permalink structure to `directory/tag/foo-tag` all without the extra work of registering custom rewrite rules and filtering the tag link so that it uses the `directory` base.

Comment: I am using a custom taxonomy. For example, Locations. So the links are /news/locations/new-york/. I dont want /news/ in it, I want /directories/. I also need /directories/ because I only want to show posts from this taxonomy. Have updated my post to show the locations in the URL perhaps it explains it better.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and in that case, then you'd want to disable the front base in the permalink - see my answer for more details. (I used `directory/location`, but just change it to whatever you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `/news/` part is called **front base** and it could also be `/foo/bar/`, i.e. having multiple "folders", and if you don't want the front base to be prepended to the permalink of posts in your post type or terms in your custom taxonomy, then set `with_front` in the `rewrite` argument to `false`, like so:

```php
// Register the "directory" post type.
register_post_type( 'directory', array(
    'label'   => 'Directories',
    'public'  => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug'       => 'directory',
        // If the front base is /news/ and this is true (which is the default value),
        // then the post permalink would be example.com/news/directory/<post slug>.
        // So set this to false if you don't want the /news/ in the permalink.
        'with_front' => false,
    ),
) );

// Register the "location" taxonomy.
register_taxonomy( 'location', 'directory', array(
    'label'   => 'Locations',
    'public'  => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug'       => 'directory/location',
        // If the front base is /news/ and this is true (which is the default value),
        // then the term permalink would be example.com/news/directory/location/<term slug>.
        // So set this to false if you don't want the /news/ in the permalink.
        'with_front' => false,
    ),
) );
```

And then be sure to flush the rewrite rules by simply visiting the Permalink Settings page. (No need to click on the Save Changes button, unless of course if you changed something in the form on the page)

Comment: Ahh, its the 'rewrite' parameter for register_taxonomy! Not sure how I missed that. Thanks

Comment: So, would you please accept my answer? (It's nice to see the "green icon" next to questions with an accepted answer..) Or do you want to post an answer?.. :)

Comment: Done! Sorry I forgot about that, I did vote it up though :)